# norm equivalence : $\mathbb S^2(0,T)=\mathbb H^2(0,T)$?

Tags: probability, general-topology, normed-spaces, stochastic-analysis

Let $\mathbb S^2(0,T)$ be the set of pregressively measurable processes s.t :
$$
Y\in \mathbb S^2(0,T)\ \Leftrightarrow\ \parallel Y\parallel_{\mathbb S^2(0,T)}=\mathbb E (\sup_{t\in[0,T]} \mid Y_t\mid^2)^{1/2}<+\infty
$$

Let $\mathbb H^2(0,T)$ be the set of pregressively measurable processes s.t :
$$
Z\in \mathbb H^2(0,T)\ \Leftrightarrow\ \parallel Z\parallel_{\mathbb H^2(0,T)}=\mathbb E (\int^T_0 \mid Z_t\mid^2dt)^{1/2}<+\infty
$$

**Do we have $\mathbb S^2(0,T)=\mathbb H^2(0,T)$ ?**

Does this following argument enough for stipulating the equality ?
$$
\sup_{t\in[0,T]} \mid X_t\mid^2 \leq \int^T_0 \mid X_t\mid^2dt\leq T\sup_{t\in[0,T]} \mid X_t\mid^2
$$

Comment: Someone can confirm or not the argument  ?